# Sum of the first n terms of Central polygonal numbers (the Lazy Caterer's sequence)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How do you find the sum of the first $n$ terms of the Central polygonal numbers (the Lazy Caterer's sequence):
[A000124 - OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000124)

$1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37, 46, \ldots$

I tried but could not solve.

Please help!!!!

I am from Brazil.

Comment: This is not a geometric progression.  What is the formula for the general term?

Comment: Yes. I am noob sorry.

Comment: $2 = 1 + 1, 4 = 2 + 2, 7 = 4 + 3, 11 = 7 + 4$, etc. Do you see the pattern here?

Comment: Yes. But How know sum ?

Comment: Please give us some context.  Where does this problem come from?  Is it for a course?  If so, what are you studying?  This will allow someone to give you an answer appropriate to your level.

Comment: In addition to this not being a "geometric" progression, since the progression is all positive numbers, getting larger and larger, there **cannot** be a finite sum.  Perhaps you want a formula for the "nth" term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of deriving the $i$-th term.

One easy way is the following:

Notice that if the $i$-th term is $t_i$ then

$t_2 - t_1 = 1$

$t_3 - t_2 = 2$

$.$

$.$

$.$

$t_i - t_{i-1} = i-1$

Add all the above equations to obtain

$t_i - 1 = \frac{i(i-1)}{2}$

or, $t_i = \frac{1}{2}(i^2 - i + 2)$

Finally

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n t_i 
= \frac{1}{2} \left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 - \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i + \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n 2 \right)
= \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 2n\right]
= \frac{n(n^2+5)}{6}$

Comment: Thank you. Help me up.

Answer (score 3):

You sequences seems to be defined as $\begin{cases}u_1=1\\u_{n+1}=u_n+n\end{cases}$

Thus $S(n+1)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} u_i=u_1+\sum_{i=2}^{n+1} u_i=1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(u_i+i)=1+S(n)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=1+S(n)+\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$

This gives a telescopinc formula $S(n+1)-S(n)=1+\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$

Which sums to $$S(n+1)-S(1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\dfrac{i(i+1)}{2}\right)=n+\dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$$

Since $S(1)=1$ we have $$S(n)=\dfrac{n(n^2+5)}{6}$$

Comment: Working formula. Thank you 